# Html Paypal payment and emailing user at the same time

Tags: html, css, server, paypal, web-development-server

I am working on a website where I use paypal as a payment system. But I have a problem. What I want is to happen is that when I click on the paypal button it will take me to a new page where the client can buy my product, (this works completly fine). But I also want an email to be sent. The email part I figured out but I can't figure out to run the code at the same time as it redirects the client to the paypal page.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/Pilhamre/pen/gOabjqz)

This is the button that takes care of the email:

```
<button formaction="/contact" type="submit" class="paypal-btn-check" onclick="simple_gaming_radio_check();">
```

This is the code that redirects the user to the paypal page:

```
<input formaction="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
          <input formaction="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="W6SHV472B68TC">
          <input type="submit" formaction="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" name="submit">
```

**Html Code**

```
<body>
<section>
    <div class="contact-container">
        <h1>Contact</h1>
        <form method="post">
            <div class="contact-input-container">
                <div>
                    <input formaction="/contact" name="email" class="contact-input contact-email" type="text" placeholder="name@gmail.com" autocomplete="off">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input formaction="/contact" name="subject" class="contact-input contact-subject" type="text" placeholder="subject.." autocomplete="off">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <textarea formaction="/contact" name="message" class="contact-input contact-message" type="text" placeholder="message.."></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button formaction="/contact" type="submit" class="paypal-btn-check" onclick="simple_gaming_radio_check();">
              <input formaction="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
              <input formaction="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="W6SHV472B68TC">
              <input type="submit" formaction="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" name="submit">
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to call your sending email function via the onclick event in Javascript.

```
    <body>
    <section>
    <div class="contact-container">
        <h1>Contact</h1>
        <form method="post">
            <div class="contact-input-container">
                <div>
                    <input formaction="/contact" name="email" class="contact-input contact-email" type="text" placeholder="name@gmail.com" autocomplete="off">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input formaction="/contact" name="subject" class="contact-input contact-subject" type="text" placeholder="subject.." autocomplete="off">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <textarea formaction="/contact" name="message" class="contact-input contact-message" type="text" placeholder="message.."></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button formaction="/contact" type="submit" class="paypal-btn-check" onclick="simple_gaming_radio_check();">
              <input formaction="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
              <input formaction="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="W6SHV472B68TC">
              <input type="submit" onclick="sendMail()" formaction="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" name="submit">
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

Your javascript code will be something like this

```
   function sendMail(){
      //Your sending mail code will go here
      alert("Mail Sent")
   }
```